# Splitting a stack (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

How is it done in order to split a stack into separate stacks in an alternative manner?

For an instance, I want to split stack `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` to `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]` and `[2, 4, 6, 8]`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [step size on the slice](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) of the stack:

```
In [11]:
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(lst[::2])
print(lst[1::2])

[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

So the syntax here `::2` translates to `<start pos>:<end pos>:<step size>`

So the first `lst[::2]` goes in steps of 2 the second `lst[1::2]` starts from `1` and goes in step size 2

Comment: Realized that quickly!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to separate odd and even

```
 lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
 odd = [ i for i in lst if i%2]
 even= [ i for i in lst if i%2 == 0 ]
```

Comment: You might assume that, the OP doesn't state it. In fact, I would assume that they want to simply split the list into two taking alternate entries. It is hard to know for sure, I agree, but I think your assumption is incorrect.